# Inheritance issues about Threads OnClickListener (android)

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an textview who can enter a key word , and I press the button,it will show a parse Information  over the current one.But this works fine however it's the close button that doesn't work.In first code,it have some problem about ThreadException .

```
private OnClickListener btsearchitemListener = new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {         
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                          
                        editText1.setHint("");
                        URL url ;
                        String Http_keyWord = "https://tw.search.bid.yahoo.com/search/auction/product?p=%sqt=product&cid=0&clv=0", Http, Keyword;   
                        AllDatainfos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
                        Keyword = editText1.getText().toString().trim();

                        tvspottempp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp);
                        tvspottempp.setText("Keyword"+Keyword);

                        try
                        {
                            Http = String.format(Http_keyWord, UTF8EnCode(Keyword));
                            //Http = String.format(Http_keyWord, Keyword);
                            tvspottempp1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp1);
                            tvspottempp1.setText("Http"+Http);                          
                            url = new URL(Http);
                            tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp2);
                            tvspottempp2.setText("url"+url);
                            Document doc ;
                            /*tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp2);
                            tvspottempp2.setText("doc"+doc);*/
                            doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 30000000);   
                            tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp2);
                            tvspottempp2.setText("doc2"+doc);
                            Elements paramDocuments = doc.select("#srp_result_list, #srp_gaze_list").select(".grid-type.yui3-g > *");
                            Iterator localIterator = paramDocuments.select("#srp_result_list, #srp_gaze_list").select(".grid-type.yui3-g > *").iterator();
                          while (true)
                          {
                            if (!localIterator.hasNext())
                              return;
                            Element localElement1 = (Element)localIterator.next();
                            try
                            {
                              SearchResultItem localSearchResultItem = new SearchResultItem();
                              Element localElement2 = localElement1.select(".wrap").first();
                              parsePhoto(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);
                              parsePrice(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);
                              parseTitle(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);                    
                            }
                            catch (Exception localException2)
                            {
                              localException2.printStackTrace();
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        catch (Exception localException1)
                        {
                          localException1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };              
                }
            };
```

---

```
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10734
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6804)
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:358)
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7646)
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.widget.TextView.setHint(TextView.java:4588)
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at com.example.rsbuyclient.User_menu$1$1.run(User_menu.java:132)
04-21 20:12:12.681: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

---

So I chang thread methods.I create two thread in new code. But thread1 can't inheritance thread2 declare variables.For example : Url Http ... etc.
How can I  resolve it . Thanks.

```
private OnClickListener btsearchitemListener = new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //thread1 to get url
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                          
                    editText1.setHint("");

                    URL url ;
                    String Http_keyWord = "http://tw.search.bid.yahoo.com/search/auction/product?p=%s", Http, Keyword;
                    //String Http_keyWord = "https://tw.search.yahoo.com/search?p=u+zj6&fr=yfp&ei=utf-8&v=0", Http, Keyword;    


                    AllDatainfos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

                    Keyword = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
                    tvspottempp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp);
                    tvspottempp.setText("Keyword"+Keyword);                                             

                    Http = String.format(Http_keyWord, UTF8EnCode(Keyword));
                    tvspottempp1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp1);
                    tvspottempp1.setText("Http"+Http);
                     }
                   });

                    //thread2 to parse html
                    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                         public void run() {
                        //TagNode tagNode;
                        try
                        {
                            url = new URL(Http.toString());
                            tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp2);
                            tvspottempp2.setText("url "+url );

                            //tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean(url);
                            Document doc;                   
                            doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 30000000);
                            tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp2);
                            tvspottempp2.setText("doc"+doc);

                            Elements paramDocuments = doc.select("#srp_result_list, #srp_gaze_list").select(".grid-type.yui3-g > *");
                            Iterator localIterator = paramDocuments.select("#srp_result_list, #srp_gaze_list").select(".grid-type.yui3-g > *").iterator();

                          while (true)
                          {
                            if (!localIterator.hasNext())
                              return;
                            Element localElement1 = (Element)localIterator.next();
                            try
                            {
                              SearchResultItem localSearchResultItem = new SearchResultItem();
                              Element localElement2 = localElement1.select(".wrap").first();
                              parsePhoto(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);
                              parsePrice(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);
                              parseTitle(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);                    
                            }
                            catch (Exception localException2)
                            {
                              localException2.printStackTrace();
                            }
                          }
                        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (Exception localException1)
                        {
                          localException1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }});
                    thread1.start();
                    thread2.start();
                 }  
              };
```

---

And I try to use runOnUiThread , but have problem about Parameter transformation.

It's change 
final URL url ; 
final String Http_keyWord = "tw.search.bid.yahoo.com/search/auction/product?p=%s";, Http, Keyword;

If  Parameter transformation
url = new URL(Http.toString()); will be error

```
    private OnClickListener btsearchitemListener = new OnClickListener() 
        {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                          
                editText1.setHint("");

                final URL url ;
                final String Http_keyWord = "http://tw.search.bid.yahoo.com/search/auction/product?p=%s", Http, Keyword;
                //String Http_keyWord = "https://tw.search.yahoo.com/search?p=u+zj6&fr=yfp&ei=utf-8&v=0", Http, Keyword;    


                AllDatainfos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

                Keyword = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
                tvspottempp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp);
                tvspottempp.setText("Keyword"+Keyword);                                             

                Http = String.format(Http_keyWord, UTF8EnCode(Keyword));
                tvspottempp1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp1);
                tvspottempp1.setText("Http"+Http);

                User_menu.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                     public void run() {
                    //TagNode tagNode;
                    try
                    {
                        url = new URL(Http.toString());
                        tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp2);
                        tvspottempp2.setText("url"+url);

                        //tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean(url);
                        Document doc;                   
                        doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 30000000);
                        tvspottempp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvspottempp2);
                        tvspottempp2.setText("doc"+doc);

                        Elements paramDocuments = doc.select("#srp_result_list, #srp_gaze_list").select(".grid-type.yui3-g > *");
                        Iterator localIterator = paramDocuments.select("#srp_result_list, #srp_gaze_list").select(".grid-type.yui3-g > *").iterator();

                      while (true)
                      {
                        if (!localIterator.hasNext())
                          return;
                        Element localElement1 = (Element)localIterator.next();
                        try
                        {
                          SearchResultItem localSearchResultItem = new SearchResultItem();
                          Element localElement2 = localElement1.select(".wrap").first();
                          parsePhoto(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);
                          parsePrice(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);
                          parseTitle(localSearchResultItem, localElement2);                    
                        }
                        catch (Exception localException2)
                        {
                          localException2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                      }
                    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (Exception localException1)
                    {
                      localException1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }});
                 }
               }).start();
             }  
          };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulate views inside a `Thread`, like you are doing. You are free to do whatever you want using `Threads`, but to manipulate any `View` you have to do it, exclusively, from the UI thread or you will get that fatal exception. You have several ways to do it:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         ... manipulate your view
    }
});
```

`runOnUiThread` is a method that belongs to the `Activity`.

or at a view level:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         ... manipulate your view
    }
});
```

All views have a `Handler` that you can use to post `Runnables` that will be executed in the UI Thread.

or even

```
view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         ... manipulate your view
    }
}, DELAY_TIME);
```

you can schedule a `Runnable` to run with a time delay in the UI Thread

Besides, check out the class `AsyncTask`. It's the recommended method for doing the kind of background stuff you are doing, and allows to run code on a background thread and provides a place to write code that runs on the UI thread (`onPostExecute`) and even a means to report progress. Your code will be much cleaner instead of that big mess you have now :)

Comment: I try to use runOnUiThread , but have problem about Parameter transformation.

Comment: It's change  final URL url ; and final String Http_keyWord = "http://tw.search.bid.yahoo.com/search/auction/product?p=%s", Http, Keyword;

Comment: yeah, external variables inside runOnUiThread have to be final, because runOnUiThread's code executes asynchronously in the UI thread, so it needs a stable copy of the variable, if it was allowed to change it could have unpredictable results !

Comment: "only one thread" you mean on AsyncTasks? Well, you can span as many AsyncTasks as you want, each of them will run in its own thread. You can further define if those threads will run in parallel or serial via Executor. Much easier than it sounds, really, have a look at some examples here in StackOverflow on AsyncTasks and try to implement next things like this one with that class. It's really convenient.

Comment: Thanks, now I only have  parse html problem in this code .